# Need to Add the Last Two Octets to a List of IP Ranges with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a large list of IP ranges in a file that look like 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, etc.. and I want to add 0.0/16 to each of them so they look like 10.1.0.0/16

```
$list = gc C:\temp\list.txt
foreach ($ip in $list){
```

Not sure how to do the rest. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$add = '.0.0/16'
$list = gc C:\temp\list.txt
foreach ($ip in $list){$ip + $add}
```

Comment: Glad to help, if you could accept the answer that would be great. Thanks!